# Class ... not found exception with Laravel 8 + Laravel Vapor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-vapor

Setup;

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
"laravel/vapor-core": "^2.0",
"laravel/telescope": "^4",
"php": "^7.4",
```

So a little time ago I was noticing some strange exceptions in the telescope exception logging.
It's showing '**Class ... not found**' but not for a specific class, this includes models Illuminate classes, Service providers and so on.

My findings are those exceptions  probably come from running a command. I do not know which command is triggering this, it only shows up on production environment as well, probably because it's being used more than the other environments. I based this on the stack trace starting with artisan.

Here is a screenshot of some exceptions (these are just some, it's a whole list of random exceptions)
[image]

P.S the website/app is working as expected, the only thing is if I come back the next morning to work, I see those exceptions.

I tried reinstalling composer packages and a re-deploy without any effect.

Does anyone have an idea of what might cause these exceptions?

This is my post-update-cmd

```
"post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "php artisan optimize",
    "php artisan view:clear",
    "php artisan config:clear",
    "php artisan route:clear",
    "@php artisan vapor-ui:publish --ansi",
    "@php artisan telescope:publish --ansi"
],
```

Stack trace example
[image]

More exceptions (goes on on and with different classes):
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I already provided my attempts, without any success. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: I don't even know what code to share, the application itself is working fine. It's happening somewhere inside a job. I just shared some exceptions I cannot explain and are package classes (most). Like the vapor container has a different lock file sometimes. Next time I will share text. There is not much more to go on. You can see the context and yet here we are.

Comment: Spin up another staging environment and run your artisan commands manually till you see the errors.

Comment: Hi, we have a test, staging and production environment, the exceptions are only thrown on production environment. These environments are identical in AWS services.

Comment: Must be something conditional in prod or maybe look for an artisan command that never really gets fully executed in your other environments due to the lack of data.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I've been experiencing a similar issue.